# Parse a loop variable at execution time

Tags: bash, for-loop, case, nested-loops

I have the following loop:

```
for a in var1 var2;
do
    direst=$theDir/$a
    cd $direst
    case $a in
    var1)
            theUsrs=$VAR1usrs
            csvFile="$theDate"__"$b"_.csv
            sleep 5s
            ;;
    var2)
            theUsrs=$VAR2usrs
            csvFile="$theDate"_$(echo $b |awk -F, '{print $1}')__$(echo $b |awk -F, '{print $2}')_.csv
            sleep 5s
            ;;
    esac
    for b in $theUsrs;
    do
            echo " "
            echo $b $a $direst $csvFile
            sleep 2s
            cd $direst
            if [[ ! -f $csvFile ]];
            then
                    missingUsr=$b
                    echo "$csvFile is missing, creating empty file"
                    createMissing"$a"File
            fi
            cd $direst
            gzip -v $csvFile
            echo "Uploading $csvFile to New Edge"
            uploadFile
    done
done
exit
```

(uploadFile and createMissing"$a"File are functions I created before)

Now, as much as I see here, I need to create 2 different loops for each VAR, simply because `$b` (which is the second loop variable in my script) cannot be parsed before the loop starts, so I need to determine `$csvFile` for each var separately.

I can't nest the case statement inside the second loop as well, because `$theUsers` has not been determined yet.

Is there a way to make `$b` in `$csvFile` be parsed only when the second loop starts (just like EnableDelayedExpantion in batch)?

Comment: Couple of things missing to understand the script.  Provide sample values for theDir, $VAR1usrs, $VAR2usrs.  Looks like there a loop of logic here.  You need $b in the code for $a, but $b is dependent on code in your $a loop...?  If you explain what you are trying to do, we might figure a way out of that logic.

Comment: Or split the $b loop in a function, and call it right after `theUsrs=$VAR1usrs` line in the case statement on $a, passing it the required values as arguments.

Comment: Actually, the values of $VAR1 and $VAR2 usrs, don't really matter (just a list of users for 2 different services, I need to upload a csv file for each user and create those which are missing), as well as the value for $theDir, which is just the directory I use to store those files (each VAR has a directory for it's own files). Only thing I need to know is if I can determine an incomplete value for $csvFile, which contains the value of $b (the second loop variable) before I run the second loop, and make $csvFile being parse only when I call it.